# Agregar Cache control a Nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Se me ha solicitado integrar Cache-Control a la pagina web que estoy haciendo.

La configuración del archivo server.js es la siguiente

```
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()

 app.use(express.static('dist/tiptiweb'))

 app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Listening on port 8080!'))
```

Cuando examino un archivo desde consola, el Cache control me sale en max-age=0

Como puedo colocar un max-age de un dia en mi archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trabajar con [HTTP caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), en tu aplicación de [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/), puedes establecer la cabecera de [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#Control_del_almacenamiento_en_cach%C3%A9) a todas las respuestas a las solicitudes que recibas en tu servidor, o hacerlo de forma selectiva si ese fuera el requerimiento.

La cabecera `Cache-Control` puede recibir varios valores, entre los que se encuentran:

- `no-store`
- `no-cache`
- `private`
- `public`
- `max-age`

Nos interesa el valor `max-age`. Según la documentación, la directiva `max-age=<seconds>` indica:

> *... la máxima cantidad de tiempo que un recurso será considerado nuevo.*

Por lo tanto si deseas que el valor sea el de un día (24 horas => 1440 minutos => 86400 segundos), debemos establecer el valor de la directiva a 86400 segundos:

```
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400'
```

Para hacer esto en ExpressJS, usaremos una función middleware a nivel de aplicación ([*Application level middleware*](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application)) de la siguiente manera:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const cacheTime = 60*60*24; // 60 segundos * 60 minutos * 24 horas = 1 día
  res.set({
    'Cache-Control': `max-age=${cacheTime}`
  });
  next();
});
```

De esta forma, todas las solicitudes a nuestra aplicación serán respondidas con la cabecera `Cache-Control` que contiene la directiva `max-age=86400`.

En caso de que desees aplicar la cabecera a ciertas rutas, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if(req.url.match(/* filtro aplicado a la ruta */)){
    const cacheTime = /* el valor que desees para esta ruta */
    res.set({
      'Cache-Control': `max-age=${cacheTime}`
    });
  } else {
    const cacheTime = /* el valor que desees para el resto de rutas */
    res.set({
      'Cache-Control': `max-age=${cacheTime}`
    });
  }
  next();
});
```

Por último, recuerda que el middleware aplicado es a nivel de aplicación, por lo tanto deberías tenerlo declarado en la parte de tu código en el que realizas la configuración de tu aplicación. Usando tu ejemplo puesto en la pregunta, lo podrías hacer así:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// middleware de nivel de aplicación
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const cacheTime = 60*60*24;
  res.set({
    'Cache-Control': `max-age=${cacheTime}`
  });
  next();
});

app.use(express.static('dist/tiptiweb'));

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Listening on port 8080!'));
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea la que estabas buscando y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Puedes leer la documentación del método [`response.set()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set) para mayor información.